How to combine exception handling with a termination handler?
The high level problem I'm trying to solve is to log stacktrace for every exception that is being thrown from [legacy] code. The solution I'm trying to find an alternative to is logging stacktrace from the exception constructor. Indeed, this works only for custom type of exceptions, and that requires wrapping all other primitives just for the purpose of substituting standard exceptions with custom ones.
So, to log call stack I need to do it before unwinding the stack. This can be done from the exception constructor, or from the terminate handler. The latter approach allows logging call stack, but will terminate the program, and that may be undesirable. Here is an example: a GUI application that shall not crash, but log/display the stacktrace, and allow the user to perform another operation. But not crashing means catching exceptions, and that means stack unwinding...
Is there any good way to combine exception handling with the code that can be executed like a terminate handler (right after the exception is thrown)? For example, if the terminate handler was not declared [[noreturn]] noexcept, I could have logged call stack, and then substitute the type of exception, making it recoverable:
/*[[no-noreturn]]*/ void onTerminate() /*no-noexcept*/ {
    std::string stackDescription = ...
    throw MyExceptionToBeCaughtInGUI(std::move(stackDescription));
}
 
int main() {
    std::set_terminate(&onTerminate);
    try {
        // run...
    }
    catch(const MyExceptionToBeCaughtInGUI &e) {
        displayCallStack(e.stackDescription);
    }
}

For sure this code doesn't work. What can be done instead?
Update: the answer to this question doesn't provide a solution for my case. I know how to log stack when I'm terminating the program, but the essential part of my question is how to do that without termination. Please de-duplicate.

Saving the stacktrace in the exception constructor is the way to do it

@AlanBirtles, how would you do it without rewriting STL?

@AlanBirtles, the essential part of my question is that I neither can terminate the program nor to substitute standard exceptions with custom ones. Please de-duplicate, as the question you refer to is different.


a GUI application that shall not crash, but log/display the stacktrace, and allow the user to perform another operation.
This isn't always an option, unless you mean that the application effectively restarts (in a loop) upon catching an exception


The linked question is essentially the same as yours, the answers don't tell you how to print a stacktrace for a caught exception because its simply not possible, the information isn't saved, you need to save it yourself

@AlanBirtles, if you are answering my question, please do that as an official answer. If you are comparing the questions for the reason to close my question, please ensure that they are 100% identical. I insist that they are not. The authors of those questions were satisfied with the answers, but I'm not.

@TerenceSimpson Not necessarily the application needs to be restarted. The same library can be used in two apps. The first one (production) shall be terminated in case of exception. The second one (designed for debugging) shall not, as restarting means time consuming reloading data.

@DmitryKuzminov The point is that when you handle the exception, the stack has been unwound back to that point. So nothing of the state of the program exists and needs to be recreated. Generally speaking, if an exception makes its way back up to main() then you can't just continue as if nothing happened, you must re-set the state to a valid one (so restart the program)

@TerenceSimpson, I understand that, so my question is about logging the stack before unwinding. It would be nice to have a "non-terminate" handler that is called if appropriate catch is not found, and that allows to prevent termination (for example by throwing another exception that can be handled gracefully). There could be unusual hacks (for example here I found some, but neither solves my problem: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/using-stdterminate/). Anyway, I find my question to be different from the one referenced by Alan Birtles.
